# Как в CSS задать размещение элементов в блоке?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

У меня есть html файл, мне нужно, чтобы слово Tasks было по середине блока, а кнопка по краю, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<h1> <div id="blog">
    Tasks
    <%= link_to "+", new_task_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div></h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, например, с помощью абсолютного позиционирования:

```css
.col-md-12 {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#blog {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#blog:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1>Tasks</h1>
  <div id="blog">кнопка</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Comment: Ещё подскажите, если не трудно, как сделать так, чтобы панель растягивалась в право и в лева по ширине окна браузера

Comment: @НиколайСеменов, в моём примере она и растягивается во всю ширину. У Вас, очевидно, ей что-то мешает, но без полного вашего кода я не смогу угадать.

Comment: если у Вас будет время и желание посмотреть, вот ссылка на GitHab https://github.com/Nikolui333/Task2.git

Comment: Путь ко всем html файлам: app/view/tasks, к css файлам: app/assets/stylesheets

Comment: Там загружен код ещё до предложенных Вами изменений

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с использованием flex:

```css
.col-md-12 {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#blog {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#blog:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1>Tasks</h1>
  <div id="blog" class="ml-auto">кнопка</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ещё подскажите, если не трудно, как сделать так, чтобы панель растягивалась в право и в лева по ширине окна браузера